# How to compare value in the Table rate and display the equivalent Price from Table Rate

Tags: onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, table-rates

I have a table rate imported and it's rule is Weight vs. Destination. On my onepage checkout I want to check the weight of the total Items ordered over the Table Rates weight and Display the equivalent Price. I want to show the customer the total weight and the corresponding price of the order in the Payment Information prior to Order Review.

Can anyone help me how? I'm not an expert. I just want to know which part on how to do the checking of the total weight over the table rate. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried importing the CSV file in the Magento backend?

Comment: Yes I did. But I want to do display it on a different block within the onepage checkout.